# Strictly positive random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

Suppose $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$ with some small $\sigma^{2}$ and largish $\mu$. Now $X$ will be rarely negative.

Suppose I need random variables that are strictly positive but otherwise normal-like. Have this kind of variables been studied before? It is not something that I find from my statistics books..

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "normal-like."

Comment: To clarify what @whuber means, normality has many aspects. The normal distribution is symmetric, has relatively light tails, sum of the normals is normal, etc. Any strictly positive distribution is asymmetric, since the values below zero are inadmissible. Hence you have to sacrifice the symmetry at the very least.

Comment: @StasK A $\text{beta}(\alpha,\alpha)$ is an example of a distribution that is both symmetric and has a corresponding r.v. that is strictly positive. I understand what you mean but I think it needs to be phrased slightly differently.

Comment: There are too many possibilities! you need to narrow the scope down a bit by explaining what you need it to do (what properties do you need it to have?)

Answer (score 6):

Depending on how "normal-like" you want your variable, you might consider a [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), in which the *logarithm* of the variable has a normal distribution. The variable itself is thus always non-negative, and for the type of distribution you specify (large mean, small variance) the variable might look close to normal itself.

For measurements on items than are necessarily non-negative, a log-normal distribution can be more appropriate than a normal distribution if the measurement error is proportional to the value measured. If you try to model such measurements with a normal distribution, you can get into trouble because the variance isn't constant over the range of measurements. On the log scale, the variance would tend to be independent of the measured values.

Answer (score 5):

A [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) might fit the bill. (Or a better statistics book.) The truncated normal is obtained by discarding whatever is below zero, in your situation. The pdf, cdf and the moments are fully described in the linked Wikipedia article.